# Chrome doesn't 'save' state when going back

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, back

I built a website that uses some jquery and javascript to display a filterable slider grid of images.

When a user clicks on the slider filters to see that category items then click on an item and hit back, the browser shows the filter in the default state ('all items')

All other browsers I've tried display the last filter I clicked before going to a new page, so if I hit back, I get to see the items of the filter I chose before. All browsers but Chrome.

Does anyone know a workaround for this?

Comment: Can you share a link to the page?

Comment: http://xbn.1ae.myftpupload.com/ here it is, thanks!

Comment: Do you mean under the heading `WORK` the links for "concept figure", "cover", etc? When I click one of the links and then click one of the images and then go back, it always takes me back to "all" no matter what browser I use and I've tried Chrome, Firefox, IE and Edge, so I can't seem to recreate your desired behaviour.

Comment: Also, if you make the window too narrow the thumbnails in About Us become the same size as the image viewer.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback Rob! It is really strange I do get the desired behaviour in Firefox and Safari (can't really test pc I dont own one :o )